# Unable to insert record in MySql using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I am new to Java and MYSql in fact using this combination first time and facing real trouble. I want to insert few records in a table but unable to do so. Following are the fields and datatype in the table named tbl_cdr in MySql.

```
**Field**        **Type**
DATEANDTIME  datetime NULL
VALUE1       int(50) NULL
VALUE2       varchar(50) NULL
VALUE3       varchar(50) NULL
VALUE4       varchar(50) NULL
VALUE5       varchar(50) NULL
```

The record I want to insert contains following values
2014-05-19 02:37:18, 405, MGW190514023718eab4, 923016313475, IN, ALERTSC

I am using following query and statements to Insert record in table

```
 sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_cdr (DATEANDTIME,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4,VALUE5)" + "VALUES ("+ forDateAndTime.format(date) + ", " + columnsList.get(1) + ", " + columnsList.get(2) + ", " + columnsList.get(3)  + ", " + columnsList.get(4) + ", " + columnsList.get(5) + ")";

try
        {
            Statement qryStatement = conn.createStatement();

            qryStatement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery);
            qryStatement.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(CdrProject.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

But when I reach the statement qryStatement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery); exception is thrown as:

> MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near '02:37:18, 405, MGW190514023718eab4,
>   923016313475, IN, ALERTSC)' at line 1

Comment: Strings and datetimes need to be quoted with `'` as in for example `'2014-03-02'`. Even better, use prepared statements and parameters, that will make your code safe from SQL injection and most likely faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting the date incorrectly. MySQL allows you to insert a string literal or a number.

You're trying to use 02:37:18  as a number, when really you should be using it as a string literal: '02:37:18'

[Here is the MySql Reference describing this.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-literals.html)

You're also not treating your varchars as strings either, they should be enclosed with quotes.

Answer (score 1):

value2 ,value3 ,value4 and value 5 are varchars so it should be written within `''`.

Do like this

```
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO tbl_cdr (DATEANDTIME,VALUE1,VALUE2,VALUE3,VALUE4,VALUE5)" + "VALUES ("+ forDateAndTime.format(date) + ", " + columnsList.get(1) + ", '" + columnsList.get(2) + "',' " + columnsList.get(3)  + "',' " + columnsList.get(4) + "',' " + columnsList.get(5) + "')";
```

Comment: I tried above query it's working fine in mysql but i am facing problem when i want to do this using java and exception is thrown on statement qryStatement.executeUpdate(sqlQuery); I am not finding any solution to this since all the sites use same method that I am already using